# Indirect access to a protected member of an object in PHP

Tags: php

I have a question about pointer in PHP.

In a A class i have :

```
protected $startDate;
public function getStartDate()
{
    return $this->startDate;
}
public function setStartDate($startDate)
{
    $this->startDate = $startDate;
}
```

I use it in my code like this :

```
$day = new \DateInterval('P1D');
$a->startDate->add($day);
```

**Result : "Cannot access protected property" (as expected)**

---

if I try :

```
$day = new \DateInterval('P1D');

print_r($a->getStartDate());

$date = $a->getStartDate();
$date->add($day);

print_r($a->getStartDate());
die();
```

Result :

```
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2012-11-08 00:00:00
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => Europe/Paris
)

DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2012-11-09 00:00:00
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => Europe/Paris
)
```

I modified a protected value without the setter

I think that I modified the date value because it was returned as a pointer by the getter method. 
I don't understand how I could modify a protected value without using a setter method.

Do you know why?

Thanks

Edit : Ok the member of my A class is a DateTime Object as I explained.
If I want it to be really protected, maybe I have to make a "timestamp" member and return a new DateTime of my timestamp (or clone the member).

Thanks again !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects are always passed by *reference*. To be more exact, there's only one object, and a variable just holds a reference to the object. By assigning the variable value to another variable, you copy the value, but that value is only a reference to the object.

In short: When working with objects in PHP, you're always passing around *the object* and all modifications to it will be visible to everyone who can see the object.

If you want to break that reference, [`clone`](http://php.net/clone) the object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
protected $startDate;
public function getStartDate()
{
    return clone $this->startDate;
}
public function setStartDate($startDate)
{
    $this->startDate = $startDate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With `$date = $a->getStartDate();` you create a new variable.
With `$date->add($day);` you change that new variable's value, not the origin.